# Email Recipients Quota Limits: 1500/day OR 1500/24hrs?

Tags: google-apps-script

The documentation says: 1500/day limit.

I sent about 1400 emails to different recipients yesterday. Today my quota says I have 100 remaining, not 1500 again, even though it is the next day. So I used the remaining 100, and tried sending a few more but got the limit error/warning. Does anybody know when I can expect to send the rest of my emails today.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I always thought it would refresh each email sent 24 hours later. But when your quota gets refreshed, please let us know. Also, not that the quota is per recipient, not email, so if one cc a lot of people the quota will get reduced a lot faster.

Comment: I finished sending my 1400 yesterday at around 9-10pm, did the remaining 100 around 5am this morning, and I noticed it was reset to 1500 around 11am this morning. So, it was neither technically the next day (in my opinion) or 24hrs later. Even though it would be nice to know with consistency when you can expect it to reset, I got my emails sent in time, so in this case it worked more or less fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Email quotas do not get reset at specific times (such as midnight). Rather, the reset happens according to when the quota is used. You can expect that the reset will occur (roughly) 24 hours after the **first** email of the quota is sent (not the last one).

For example, if you have a quota of 1500/day, and start sending mails at around 3pm and then exhaust that quota at 10pm, you can expect the quota will refresh sometime around 3pm the next day.

When the reset happens, it refreshes the entire quota to its maximum limit.